# Git merge--no-ff with -m option

Tags: git, github, merge

Have a quick but very specific question. I am merging a branch back to my master using the --no-ff option and I am also adding a merge commit message using -m in the same command (`git merge --no-ff -m"message" feature1`). I have github setup to use vim as my default commit message editor and via vim I have my commit body limited to 72 characters.

When I try to do a merge commit with a message as described above I lose control over limiting the number of characters that are allowed in the body. Is there any way to use the merge-no-ff and force it to open vim for the merge message or alternatively use -m and force it to a new line manually when I know I have hit 72 characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `vim` has probably some hook configured for `COMMIT_EDITMSG` but merge commit messages are go into `MERGE_MSG`

Comment: You mean if there is a character that allows you to write your comments in more than one line when you use the -m option?

Comment: Hi Arkadiusz, I have purposely set vim and git to limit my commit messages to 72 but it seems neither of these settings will be used when I use the -m option

Comment: Hi Riccardo, I would rather the merge message prompt me via an editor to enter the merge message as it currently does for commit messages but I realize this may not be possible. Failing that yes I would love a way to use the -m option to write the comment over two lines manually. Do you know of a way to do this ?

Comment: Actually, I tried and usign `git merge some_branch --no-ff` it open my predefined editor and I am allowed to change the commit comment... does it usually open the editor when you commit something?

Comment: Hi Riccardo, thanks for the quick reply, yes my commits always open my editor when I leave out the -m option. If yours opens using that exact command there must be some config options in git that deal with merging as there is for commits. I will start looking into merge config in git. I tried the git command exactly as you wrote it to be sure but still no joy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-m` flag takes a pre-formatted commit message.  If you wish to include newlines or other forms of whitespace within it, you must, well, include the newlines or other forms of whitespace.

For instance, to set the merge message to:

```
hello

world
```

you could use:

```
git merge --no-ff -m 'hello

world'
```

(assuming a typical shell such as `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` that allows embedded newlines in quoted strings; this method does not work in `tcsh`, for instance).

In general, if you have a complex message you want to supply, you are probably better off putting it into a file and using the `-F` flag, instead of the `-m` flag.  See also the `-t` flag, which takes a *template* file, and the `-e` (or `--edit`) flag, which forces the use of your interaction editor even when an initial message is supplied with `-m` or `-F`.

To put it another way:

- use `-t <template>` to run the editor on the template file; or
- use `-m <message>` to *not* run the editor and supply a message as a string; or
- use `-F <file>` to *not* run the editor and supply a message from a file; or
- use `-m <message> --edit` or `-F <file> --edit` to supply a message but run the editor after all.

See [the `git commit` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you so much Torek, this is absolutely perfect. I really really appreciate you help on this and thank you for putting so much detail into your answer, it really helps a git newbie like myself. I will be using the -e option in my merge command to force the editor. This will allow me to do a --no-ff merge with a message that follows the general commit message format I have been using. In case it helps anyone else my merge command will now look as follows, `git merge --no-ff -m "message" -e featureBranchToMerge`.